# How to read from Access databases into visualbasic

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to be able to see a line of text in a textbox from an access database.

I know how to write and delete data from the database through visual basic code, but how can you read data?

If for example, I have something that says "Hi" saved in my database. How can I use a line of code in visual basic to read "Hi" and then show it in a textbox or simply in the console app?

Comment: You're really going to have to be specific here...What have you tried? What's the structure of your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SayHi()
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strCity As String

   Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Foo FROM tblCustomers WHERE Foo = " & "'Hi'")

   'Begin row processing
   Do While Not rst.EOF
       MsgBox rst!Foo
   Loop

   'Cleanup
   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```